# how to print list of list and other type of data in jsp

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp, jstl

i am trying to fetch data from database in spring mvc, this is my code for fetching data

```
@Override
public List getOrderDetail(Integer shop_id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    SQLQuery query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(
            "SELECT order_id,shop_id,delivery_address,total_amount FROM master_order WHERE shop_id =" + shop_id);

    SQLQuery query1 = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(
            "SELECT itm.image,itm.name,itm.brand,odr.quantity,itm.offerprice,(itm.offerprice*odr.quantity) AS Total,modr.cust_id FROM master_order modr\r\n"
                    + "INNER JOIN tblorder odr ON modr.order_id = odr.order_id INNER JOIN item itm on odr.item_id = itm.item_id WHERE modr.shop_id ="+shop_id);

    query.setResultTransformer(Criteria.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP);
    query1.setResultTransformer(Criteria.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP);

    List results = query.list();
    List results1 = query1.list();

    results.add(results1);

    System.out.println(results);

    return results;
}
```

above `System.out.println(results);` statement give following output

```
[{shop_id=1, delivery_address=1, abc, xyz, aaa, USA, order_id=6, total_amount=1800}, [{image=Screenshot (19).png, quantity=8, Total=800, name=DhruvRajkotiya, offerprice=100, brand=gsgsrgs, cust_id=2}, {image=Screenshot (19).png, quantity=10, Total=1000, name=qwe, offerprice=100, brand=asdf, cust_id=2}, {image=Screenshot (19).png, quantity=1, Total=100, name=ewq, offerprice=100, brand=gsgsrgs, cust_id=2}]]
```

i want print order_id as well as {image=Screenshot (19).png, quantity=10, Total=1000, name=qwe, offerprice=100, brand=asdf, cust_id=2} in jsp page

this is my controller code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/notifications", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String notifications(Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {
    if (request.getSession().getAttribute("shopkeeper") == null) {
        return "redirect:login";

    } else {
        Shopkeeper sp = (Shopkeeper) request.getSession().getAttribute("shopkeeper");
        model.addAttribute("order", shopkeeperService_shopkeeper.getOrderDetail(sp.getSk_id()));
        return "shopkeeper/notifications";
    }
}
```

this is my jsp code

```
<div class="row">
                    <c:forEach items="${ order}" var="order">
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-header" style="padding-bottom: 5px;">
                                <h6># ${order.shop_id }</h6>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <div class="col-lg-2" style="float: left;">Image</div>
                                <div class="col-lg-2" style="float: left;">Product name</div>
                                <div class="col-lg-2" style="float: left;">Product brand
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-1" style="float: left;">Quantity</div>
                                <div class="col-lg-1" style="float: left;">Unit Price</div>
                                <div class="col-lg-1" style="float: left;">Total</div>
                                <div class="col-lg-3" style="float: left;">Approve of
                                    request</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <div class="col-lg-6" style="float: left;">Delivery
                                    Address</div>
                                <div class="col-lg-6" style="float: left;">Total Amount</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </c:forEach>
                </div>
```

i want to print 
[image: here is the design i want to create]

my question concept is order_id,address,total_amount one time and multiple bought item that can be one or more

how i can print

Answer (score 0):

You can save the list as a model attribute. For example you want to save the current user:

```
model.addAttribute("user",user);
```

and access this attribute in your jsp file inside a div maybe :

```
<div> ${user.name} </div>
```

The controller method could look like this:

```
@RequestMapping( value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.GET )
public String displayUser(final Model model)
{
   final User user = userService.findUserById(1); // here you'll provide custom implementation
   model.addAttribute("user",user);
   return "somejsppage.jsp";
}
```

If you want to add a List to your model:

```
 final List<User> users = fillUserList(); // your implementation here
 model.addAttribute("users",users);
```

You can access every element in that list via `<c:forEach>` tag:

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<html>
   <body>
      <table>
         <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
         </tr>
         <c:forEach items="${users}" var="user">
            <tr>
                <td>${user.firstName}</td>
            </tr>
         </c:forEach>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i already tried this but it gives me the error 'java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "order_id" '

Comment: when i try without results.add(results1); statement it will perfectly work

Comment: but i want mearge two result

Comment: A possible problem could be the `forEach` iterating through every item from the *results* list but at the last step, there is a `list` not an entity object, so you're trying to get the ${result.order_id} when the "result" is a list.

Comment: But when i only print order_id then also this error occurs...

Comment: Can you add the code please to your question? It would be easier to explain what you need to do. And the jsp page too. (But only the fragment where you use the result)

Comment: The `shopkeeperService_shopkeeper.getOrderDetail()` returns a `List` of objects. You can't access the *shop_id* with *order.shop_id* because the *order* is a **LIST** (you should do something like *order[0].shop_id* but you can't). If you want (for testing purposes only) you can make the `getOrderDetail()` to return a single Object not a List.

Answer (score 0):

The way to "send" some data to a JSP page is to set and pass a request (or session) attribute.

From a Servlet, which handles current request, in a doGet() or doPost() method (depending on the HTTP request method used), you can do:

```java
request.setAttribute("attributeName", attributeObject);
request.getRequestDispatcher("<name_of_your_page>.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

where the `attributeName` is a string, which will be treated as a reference to the `attributeObject` on a JSP page.

Then on the JSP page, you can use JSTL library and Expression Language (see [this tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/jstl) regarding JSTL and [this one](https://www.baeldung.com/jsp) regarding JSP & EL in general). To iterate over the list, which has been passed as a request attribute, use `<c:forEach>` tag from JSTL.

First of all you need to import the core JSTL tags by placing this line on the top of your JSP:

`<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>`

Another useful statement to put under the latter is:

`<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>`

which tells your web browser to evalue the expressions written in EL instead of including them in HTML body as a plain text.

Provided that you used the string "orders" to name the collection set as attribute, the `<c:forEach>` tag usage can look similarly as below. You'll probably want to structure it differently and the field names (like `order.order_id`) can be different in your case, but I think you can get the idea.

```jsp
<c:forEach item="order" items="${requestScope.orders}">
    <p>${order.order_id}</p>
    <p>${order.delivery_address}</p>
    ...
</c:forEach>
```